# Xamarin Forms - Navigate to Native Activity from xaml.cs

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

In my `Xamarin Forms` project, I have launcher activity i.e. `MainActivity`. I am starting Shared Application App.xaml.cs from MainActivity using following line in onCreate method.

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

I am using CustomTabbedPage, each TabbedPage has its own xaml and xaml.cs files. In one of the xaml.cs files. I need to navigate to native activity that is placed under Droid module.

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomeView());
```

Everything works fine if I navigate from one xaml view to other but I am unable to navigate to native screens from any xaml.cs file.

Comment: I think you would need to use the DependencyService to do this, as the PLC project does not know of your droid project. This way you can define an interface in the PLC and make the implementation in your Droid project. This allows you to use the native android navigation.

Comment: Do I need to pop current xaml view and unload applicatoin class App.xaml.cs?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would suppose you could just push your native view onto the navigation stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Forms doesn't support navigation to a Native Android View. But you can create a empty PCL page and use NativeView in page's custom renderer.